# Convert generic ienumerable to arraylist

Tags: c#, generics

I need to convert the linq query from generic ienumerable to arraylist.

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
         var b =
              (from myObj in myCollection
           select new myClass
           {
            Name = myObj.Name,
            ac = myObj.ac
           });
```

I have tried doing

```
b.Cast<ArrayList>();
```

but it is not working.

**Edited :**
I got it working with @devdigital solution

but i will also want to point out that at same time i found a hackish solution.

```
myArrayList.InsertRange(0, b.ToArray());
```

Comment: The `Cast<T>` extension casts each element of an `IEnumerable` and returns them as another `IEnumerable`. It is therefore not useful to convert the collection itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the constructors for the `ArrayList` type takes an `ICollection`, so you should be able to do the following:

```
var b =
    (from myObj in myCollection
     select new myClass
    {
      Name = myObj.Name,
      ac = myObj.ac
    }).ToArray();

ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList(b);
```

Comment: Doesn't `ArrayList` need an `ICollection`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but this is parameter-less. I wanted to point out that `ArrayList(IEnumerable)` does not exist.

Comment: Yes, that's why b is converted to an array with ToArray(). System.Array implements ICollection. You could also use a List of course.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I missed this, this is my fault.

Comment: Be aware that this will double the memory-allocations. First everything will be collected into the array, and afterwards the entire array is copied again into the `ArrayList`. However I can´t see any way around this.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you to use a `List<T>` rather than an `ArrayList`. You can actually use the `ToList` extension method or the `List`'s [constructor which takes an `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx):

```
var myList = b.ToList(); // either
var myListTwo = new List<myClass>(b); // or
```

`List<T>` was newly introduced with .NET 2.0 and is generic. This means it yields you values of your actual type at compile-time, which is `myClass`, instead of `object`.

**Edit:** If you actually need an `ArrayList`, you need to copy `b` twice, as it cannot deal with `IEnumerable` directly, as [devdigital pointed out in his reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9276742/17713):

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(b.ToArray());
```

Comment: I'm assuming he needs an ArrayList for some legacy API.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your `IEnumerable` to an array with `ToArray()`, then construct an `ArrayList` from that array.

```
var b = (from myObj in myCollection
         select new myClass
         {
             Name = myObj.Name,
             ac = myObj.ac
         });
var myArrayList = new ArrayList(b.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(b.ToList());
```